# Trying to recreate a __str__() method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

I have been tasked with trying to recreate the methods of an ArrayList type for python. I have been successful in recreating everything except for the str and the repr function, but since they behave mostly the same I only need help with one. Below is my code for the method, but I keep getting a Type Error stating "can only join an iterable"

```
def __str__(self):
    """Implements `str(self)`. Returns '[]' if the list is empty, else
    returns `str(x)` for all values `x` in this list, separated by commas
    and enclosed by square brackets. E.g., for a list containing values
    1, 2 and 3, returns '[1, 2, 3]'."""
    str= '['
    if len(self.data)>0:
        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            if i ==0:
                str1 = str+''.join(self[i])
            else:
                str1 = str+','+ ''.join(self[i])
        return str1+']'
    else:
        return '[]'
```

There is just one catch to all of this, and that is that I can only call the following methods to help, though this should not be a limitation for this method. Please Help!

Methods:
 lst[i] for getting and setting a value at an existing, positive index i

len(lst) to obtain the number of slots

lst.append(None) to grow the list by one slot at a %time

del lst[len(lst)-1] to delete the last slot in a list

Comment: What do you think `''.join` does? Why are you trying to call `''.join(self[i])`?

Comment: I was under the impression that it adds to a string. I'm trying to stringificate the arraylist...

Comment: `+` adds to a string. `''.join` takes an *entire sequence* of strings and adds them together. You're passing it an int.

Comment: Hmm, so you're saying I can just have str = str + self[i] + ','    I overthought this didn't I

Comment: You need to stringify the elements yourself by calling `str` on them (or at least, your docstring says to call `str` - `repr` would be the usual choice), and you only need one of `+` or `join`. `join` is a safer choice - build a list of strings to join together, and join them. `+` is dangerous for performance; it's easy to end up with quadratic runtime with `+`.

Comment: I can't use the str function because that is what I am trying to recreate. Doing so will cause infinite recursion in this case.

Comment: Call `str` *on the elements*, not on `self`.

Comment: `.join()` is only work at `iterator` of `str`. Not an element. try ",".join(self).

Comment: That didn't work either, it was just returning 0.

Comment: @user2357112, str is not callable either, I tried that too

Comment: @LucasTrestka: Because you named a variable `str`. Don't name your variables like that.

Comment: Ahh yes, that did the trick. Sorry, my mind is blah at this point. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you can use `str()` on the elements of the list; since your `__str__()` isn't calling `str(self)`, you won't have infinite recursion.

Here is one way to do it.

```
#UNTESTED
def __str__(self):
    """Implements `str(self)`. Returns '[]' if the list is empty, else
    returns `str(x)` for all values `x` in this list, separated by commas
    and enclosed by square brackets. E.g., for a list containing values
    1, 2 and 3, returns '[1, 2, 3]'."""

    # Assuming that SELF implements iteration
    return '[' + ', '.join(str(x) for x in self) + ']'

    # Assuming that iteration isn't implemented
    return '[' + ', '.join(str(self[i]) for i in range(len(self))) + ']'
```